# Offset Text Fields Text in Dynamic List View

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a dynamic **ListView** in which the **TextFields** is located, each of them has its own controller. The problem is that if I remove a few of them, the ones below will receive the text of their controllers. How can I solve this problem?

Here is my code **TextFields**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:reagent/other_views/constants.dart';

class InputTextView extends StatefulWidget {
  final bool isFinal;
  final String hintText;
  final Function onChange;
  final String baseText;
  final bool isDisable;

  InputTextView(
      {@required this.isFinal,
      @required this.onChange,
      this.hintText = '',
      this.isDisable = false,
      this.baseText});

  @override
  _InputTextViewState createState() => _InputTextViewState();
}

class _InputTextViewState extends State<InputTextView> {
  TextEditingController _textController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _textController = TextEditingController(text: widget.baseText);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 12.0),
          width: double.infinity,
          height: 50.0,
          child: Center(
            child: TextField(
              controller: _textController,
              onChanged: (text) {
                widget.onChange(text);
              },
              keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
              style: mainText,
              decoration: emptyDecorator.copyWith(
                  contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(),
                  hintText: widget.hintText,
                  hintStyle: mainLightText,
                  fillColor: Colors.green),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 12.0),
          child: Divider(
            color: widget.isFinal ? Colors.transparent : dividerColor,
            height: 1.0,
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

And my **ListView**

```
class EditProfileScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _EditProfileScreenState createState() => _EditProfileScreenState();
}

class _EditProfileScreenState extends State<EditProfileScreen> {
  IEditProfileBloc _bloc;
  List<Widget> _listItems;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _bloc = BlocProvider.of(context);
    _bloc.loadUser();
    _listItems = [];
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
        backgroundColor: backgroundColor,
        bottomOpacity: 1.0,
        elevation: 0.0,
        bottom: PreferredSize(
            child: Container(
              color: blackColor,
              height: 1.0,
            ),
            preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(1.0)),
        title: Text(
          'Регистрация профиля',
          style: mainHeaderText,
        ),
      ),
      body: Container(
        color: backgroundColor,
        child: SafeArea(
          child: StreamBuilder(
            stream: _bloc.outUserState,
            builder: (BuildContext context,
                AsyncSnapshot<EditProfileBlocModel> snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                print(snapshot.data.user.hasLicence);
                _listItems = _generateListWidgets(snapshot.data);
                return ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: _listItems.length,
                  itemBuilder: (_, index) {
                    return _listItems[index];
                  },
                );
              } else {
                return Container();
              }
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  List<Widget> _generateListWidgets(EditProfileBlocModel model) {
    List<Widget> helperListWidgets = [
      SwitchView(
        title: 'Есть лицензия',
        switchValue: model.user.hasLicence,
        onChange: (isOn) {
          _bloc.updateUserFromJson({key_user_has_licence: isOn});
        },
      ),
      if (model.user.hasLicence)
        InputTextView(
          onChange: (licenceNumber) {
            _bloc.updateUserFromJson({key_user_licence_number: licenceNumber});
          },
          hintText: 'Номер лицензии',
          baseText: model.user.licenceNumber,
          isFinal: false,
        ),
      if (model.user.hasLicence)
        InputTextView(
          onChange: (otherLicences) {
            _bloc.updateUserFromJson({key_user_other_licences: otherLicences});
          },
          hintText: 'Другая лицензия',
          baseText: model.user.otherLicences,
          isFinal: false,
        ),
      InputTextView(
        onChange: (secondPhone) {
          _bloc.updateUserFromJson({key_user_second_phone: secondPhone});
        },
        hintText: 'WhatsApp',
        baseText: model.user.secondPhone,
        isFinal: false,
      ),
      InputTextView(
        onChange: (email) {
          _bloc.updateUserFromJson({key_user_email: email});
        },
        hintText: 'Email',
        baseText: model.user.email,
        isFinal: false,
      ),
    ];
    return helperListWidgets;
  }
}
```

This is how my problem looks like.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Assign each `InputTextView` a key so the states can be properly reassigned to the widgets when one widget is removed.

Comment: Thank you! It helped me!

Comment: But now there is a new problem. After entering any character in any TextField, the field keyboard is immediately hidden

Comment: That's because you are using the `onChanged` property of the text fields to update the bloc after every letter is entered, which in turn triggers a rebuild of the widget and causes the keyboard to disappear. Instead, use the `onSubmitted` property to only trigger a refresh when the user is done entering text.

Comment: Thanks again for your help!